# Facebook не возвращает collback для протокола http

Tags: laravel

**GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (400)**
Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:

"Небезопасный вход заблокирован: Не удается получить токен доступа или войти в данное приложение с незащищенной страницы. Попробуйте перезагрузить страницу, используя префикс https://"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего пару дней назад примерно 25.10.2018  Facebook запретил возвращать colback по протоколу http

Выяснил это тем что на прошлой неделе приложение работало а сейчас перестало.
Но возможно у них какие то перестройки.... и что-то наверно придумают. Будем ждать.